# How to Relearn High School Math In Greater Depth

Tags: self-learning, education, learning

I want to go back as far as necessary in order to relearn and solidify my understanding of foundational math concepts. I did not enjoy high school math and only completed the sequence up to Algebra II as a Sophomore before really taking an interest in the subject after graduation. I studied computer science in college and took as many math classes there as I had time for, foolishly skipping remedial pre-calculus in my desire to learn more advanced concepts. Despite my shaky foundation, I was able to complete the basic calculus sequence in addition to discrete math and linear algebra, which I enjoyed immensely. While I was always able to grasp the concepts, I became increasingly aware of my lack of foundational knowledge and experience, as I struggled with long computations and proofs.

I am now self-studying linear algebra in greater depth and really enjoying it, and I realized that I could address my limitations by relearning high school and maybe even middle school math. I want to intuit the foundations so well that using them is as easy as riding a bike and they give me greater insight into more advanced problems. I know that's a tall order, but I consider this to be a personal project that will take multiple years to complete.

Also, I have a friend who participated in the high school math Olympiads and studied *The Art of Problem Solving* as a student. Would drilling competition math as an adult be a good way to deeply intuit the foundations or waste of time?

Comment: Find the pertinent Math textbooks that are *right* *for* *you*.  A specific textbook that is right for someone else might not be right for you.  Also, in my opinion, $75\% - 80\%$ of the learning takes place in the exercises, not the text.  So, you want each book to have many, many exercises for you to solve.  Attack the book(s), one at a time.  For each book, open the book to page 1, and as you are going through the book, to the very end of the book, do not skip any of the exercises.  If needed, get any help needed on any pertinent exercise.  ...see next comment

Comment: I also recommend that you keep a private notebook that contains your work on each of the exercises, in as well organized a manner as possible.  Further, there will be places in the text, outside of the exercises, that are not clear.  Each such place should be totally resolved by you, getting whatever outside help is needed, with the resolution also going into your private notebook.  Then, you have the choice of whether your notebook will be physical paper/pen, or an electronic notebook.  ...see next comment

Comment: One possible way of maintaining an electronic notebook is via the free software called [LaTex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX).  If you happen to go that route, then Latex questions should be directed to [TexSE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If you finished a calculus sequence, discrete math, and linear algebra, I find it hard to imagine you getting much out of a high-school textbook in general. If you come across some topic where you feel deficient, maybe just read up on that topic. Do you have any specific examples? You mentioned struggling with "long computational proofs" - maybe just drill the techniques that were required for those proofs?

Comment: Some examples of exercises I've been having a hard time with are proving the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality for Euclidean vector spaces and calculating the pseudo-inverse of a 3x5 real valued matrix. Based on feedback I've gotten from people more experienced than me, such problems should not be that difficult.